# How to refactor method as it is too big

Tags: java, jsp

The application uses JSP's and Java. 
I have the method processPostCommands which reads in commands.
However I have a lot of 'if' statements in the method and has meant that my method is 2000 lines long.

```
if (session.getCommand().equals("SUBMIT")) {
   My code here....
```

}

```
if (session.getCommand().equals("SEARCH")) {
   Code here.....
}
```

How can i refactor this so that the method is shorter and the cyclomatic complexity is lower?

Comment: This question is far too vague. Show your full code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have at least Java 7 (or above) - use String switch:

```
switch (session.getCommand()) {
    case "SUBMIT": doSubmit(); break;
    case "SEARCH": doSearch(); break;
}
```

Implement various do-methods with your code separately.